# Webpack/Express - environment variables not found by server

Tags: node.js, express, webpack

In my Express/React app, I am using Webpack to handle server-side rendering. However, I am experiencing a build error related to environment variables that I'm trying to access in my Express server script.

In the server script, `index.js`, I am setting a few variables like so:

```
const gitCommit = process.env.GIT_COMMIT || require("./gitignore/git_commit.js"),
    buildDate = process.env.BUILD_DATE || require("./gitignore/build_date.js")
```

And since I am running a test production build on my local machine, I delete the `gitignore/` directory and set those environment variables:

```
$ export GIT_COMMIT="test commit hash"
$ export BUILD_DATE="test build date"
```

Then I `npm run build`, which executes the following scripts:

```
"build:client": "webpack --config webpack.config.js",
"build:server": "webpack --config webpack.server.config.js",
"build": "npm run build:client && npm run build:server"
```

`build:client` executes with no problem, but `build:server` throws errors...

```
ERROR in ./index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './gitignore/git_commit.js' in '/Users/filepath'
 @ ./index.js 12:38-74

ERROR in ./index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './gitignore/build_date.js' in '/Users/filepath'
 @ ./index.js 13:42-78
```

implying that the two environment variables referenced in `index.js` can't be found, and so it's looking for the `gitignore/` instead, which shouldn't exist (I mean, it does exist locally, but I've deleted since I'm simulating a production build).

Here is the complete `webpack.server.config.js`:

```
const fs = require("fs"),
    path = require("path")// ,
    // ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin")

module.exports = {
    "entry": path.resolve(__dirname, "index.js"),
    // keep node_module paths out of the bundle
    "externals": fs.readdirSync(path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules")).concat(["react-dom/server", "react/addons"]).reduce((ext, mod) => {
        ext[mod] = `commonjs ${mod}`
        return ext
    }, {}),
    "module": {
        "loaders": [
            {
                "exclude": /node_modules/,
                "loader": "babel-loader",
                "query": { "presets": ["react", "es2015", "stage-2"] },
                "test": /\.jsx$/
            },
            {
                "exclude": /node_modules/,
                "loader": "babel-loader",
                "query": { "presets": ["react", "es2015", "stage-2"] },
                "test": /\.js$/
            }
        ]
    },
    "node": {
        "__dirname": true,
        "__filename": true
    },
    "output": {
        "filename": "server.bundle.js"
    },
    "target": "node"
}
```

Now I expect that `gitignore/` would not be found, but what I don't understand is why the two environment variables that I set are not being detected by `index.js` - they are definitely set in the console before I even run the `build` command. If I `console.log()` them in the beginning of `webpack.server.config.js`, it logs them correctly, and if I run my development version instead (which doesn't use the server config), I can log them correctly in `index.js`.  What gives?

Node version 6.11.1, NPM version 3.10.10, Webpack version 2.6.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your environment variables are only available when Webpack runs, but not when you execute your `index.js`.
You will need to use the [EnvironmentPlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/environment-plugin/) in your Webpack config like that:

```
plugins: [new webpack.EnvironmentPlugin(['GIT_COMMIT ', 'BUILD_DATE'])]
```

That plugin will replace the variables by their actual values.

**HINT**: Do not use `||`. Webpack does not know how to optimize it. Try the ternary operator:

```
const gitCommit = (process.env.GIT_COMMIT) ? (
  process.env.GIT_COMMIT
) : (
  require('./gitignore/git_commit.js')
);
```

Webpack will bundle this to:

```
const gitCommit = (true) ? (
  "test commit hash"
) : (
  require('./gitignore/git_commit.js')
);
```

No `IgnorePlugin` is needed. Even better, with the `UglifyJSPlugin`, your code will be optimized to `const gitCommit = "test commit hash";`. In some cases `gitCommit` is removed completely as a variable. Its string value will be used instead anywhere where you applied `gitCommit`.

Comment: actually, I'm sorry, that isn't working... I added `"plugins": [new webpack.EnvironmentPlugin(["GIT_COMMIT", "BUILD_DATE"])]` to `webpack.server.config.js`, but I am still having the same problem.

Comment: There are two things I want you to do: 1. Debug your `server.bundle.js` what actually happens to `process.env` there? Is the EnvironmentPlugin actually replacing the values? 2. Run `server.bundle.js` with the env variables set on command line and see what happens.

Comment: Ok, this is interesting - I set env variables on the command line - for GIT_COMMIT, I used "TEST GIT COMMIT HASH". In my `server.bundle.js`, I got:  `gitCommit = "TEST GIT COMMIT HASH" || __webpack_require__(!(function webpackMissingModule() { var e = new Error("Cannot find module \"./gitignore/git_commit.js\""); e.code = 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'; throw e; }()))`.  So it replaced it correctly... but why the `webpackMissingModule()`?

Comment: Oh, I think I figured it out! I added `new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/gitignore/)` to the plugins, and it seems to have worked!  I still get the same `webpackMissingModule()` stuff in my `server.bundle.js`, but it doesn't throw an error.  Is that a good solution, or is a bandaid on a gunshot?

Comment: If it's good, please add it to your answer and I'll certainly accept!